# SQL Server Where Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider having the ff. table (`#temp_table`)

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 | mark |
| 2 | value2 | jim |
| 3 | value3 | taylor |
| 4 | value4 | tess |
| 5 | value5 | mark |
| 6 | value6 | jim |

How do I make a select query where first, I will exclude all rows where column2 = mark
then exclude all rows where column2 = jim and column1 = value2

The expected result set should be

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | value3 | taylor |
| 4 | value4 | tess |
| 6 | value6 | jim |

The query I have tried so far is

```
select * from #temp_table
where column2 != 'mark'
    and (column2 !='jim' and column1 != 'value2')
```

The result of my query

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | value3 | taylor |
| 4 | value4 | tess |

Comment: Don't do `!=` --> `<>` ........ `column2 <> 'mark' AND NOT (column2 ='jim' and column1 = 'value2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "negate" a group of conditions using the operator `NOT` before the group

```
select * from #temp_table
    where column2 != 'mark'
        and NOT (column2 ='jim' and column1 = 'value2')
```

More at: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp